# Perl Modification of a read-only value attempted for hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have a server that also counts the number of distinct IPs connected in a minute. I get a "Modification of a read-only value attempted" in the marked line in the code below:

```
$lsock=new IO::Socket::INET(LocalPort=>$port,Proto=>'tcp',Listen=>1,Reuse=>1);
$clients={};
while (1) {
    $sock=$lsock->accept();
    if ($sock) {
        $clients->{$sock->peerhost()}=1; # THIS LINE !!!
        ...
    }
}

# then later from an alarm signal I do:
sub save_stats {
    my $cnt=scalar keys %$clients;
    $clients={};
    ...
}
```

The error appears very rarely, once a month or less, but it's driving me insane, can someone please explain it to me why and what can I do?

Comment: Have you added `use warnings; use strict;` to your code?

Comment: No, but I'm adding it now.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I noticed that the Reuse parameter has been deprecated in favor of ReuseAddr: https://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket/INET.html

Comment: Start by adding `use strict; use warnings qw( all );` and *properly* scoping your variables using `my`. /// You mentioned signals. Make you sure you don't enable unsafe signals.

Comment: Then split that statement? `my $addr = $sock->peerhost(); $clients->{$addr} = 1;`

Comment: Thank all of you, I did all of these, now I just have to wait...

Comment: So many months have passed and the error never returned... It's a mistery.

Comment: Finally an error appeared, it says: `Use of uninitialized value $addr in hash element` at the line with `$clients->{$addr} = 1;` That would mean that $sock->peerhost() returns undef. Anyone knows how is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of investigation I found the answer. It can happen that the connection is lost between accept() and peerhost(). In this case the peeerhost() function's return value is not suitable as a hash key. The solution is very simple, if peerhost() returns a "false" ignore the connection alltogether.